# Group and values from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, concatenation, sql-server-2014

I have a table:

```
Col1   Col2
---    ---
Bar    Val1
Bar    Val2
Bar    Val3
Foo    Val4
Foo    Val5
Foo    Val6
```

I need to write a query that outputs

```
Col1         Col2
---    ----------------
Bar    Val1, Val2, Val3
Foo    Val4, Val5, Val6
```

I need to write it as a single query, so couldn't use `COALESCE()` for concatenating, as it would require using variable and loop.

My other solution was to use recursive CTE. However, I need to concatenate values for both 'Bar' and 'Foo'. I thought of `CROSS APPLY` but don't know is it possible to achieve this result with using `CROSS APPLY` and recursive CTE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server aggregate string concatenation".  This is a typical problem and the solution usually uses "for xml path".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-sql-server)

Comment: only for suggestion :: if you are going to show the result in UI, I mean you are using C#/JAVA etc. for front-end, better to do the same using PLs rather than in database level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct 
    Col1,
    (
     select STUFF((select ',' + col2 
     from yourtable b 
     where b.col1 = a.col1 for xml path('')),1,1,'')
     ) as Col2
from yourtable a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Col1 VARCHAR(100),Col2 VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
('Bar','Val1')
,('Bar','Val2')
,('Bar','Val3')
,('Foo','Val4')
,('Foo','Val5')
,('Foo','Val6');

SELECT DISTINCT Col1,Concatenated.Col2
FROM @tbl AS tbl
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT STUFF
    (
        (
            SELECT ', ' + Col2 
            FROM @tbl AS InnerTbl
            WHERE InnerTbl.Col1=tbl.Col1
            FOR XML PATH('')
        )
    ,1,2,'')
) AS Concatenated(Col2)

/* Result
Col1    Col2
Bar Val1, Val2, Val3
Foo Val4, Val5, Val6
*/
```